# Choice of tense: the story was interesting / is interesting

Tags: tense, verbs

Cannot figure out which sentence suits better:

> The story of the movie that I saw last night **was** very interesting / **is** very interesting.

When I was writing this I came across another confusion with the sentence:

> I saw a movie last night, that **had** a very interesting story / **has** a very interesting story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most natural way to reference the movie is:

> Last night I watched a movie with a really interesting storyline.

However, if you refer to the storyline separately, in the case of a movie, it can be present or past:

> Last night I watched a great movie. The storyline was/is very interesting.

The fact is that a work of literature or a film, or anything immortalized in any medium which is always accessible can be referred to in the present. However, it can also be referred to situationally in the past, in a past context.

Note that in American English, we **see** movies in a theater, and **watch** movies at home.

Comment: Does this stand for a story of a book? Last night I read a book. The story was/ is very interesting.

Comment: I can, yes, because a book is something in print that can be referred to at any time.

Comment: Are the sentences which I wrote are wrong?

Comment: @Stephie: I've changed my answer, Stephie, but if you look again there is no question.

Comment: @CocoPop Thanks, much better, And: There *is* a question, just hard to see due to bad formatting. Wll edit...